# How to animate a line string between 2 points in OpenLayers 3 map?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to draw a line between multiple points from an array of coordinates.
**My code looks like :**

```
<button onclick="drawAnimatedLine(new ol.geom.Point(6210355.674114,2592743.9994331785), new ol.geom.Point(8176927.537835015,2255198.08252584), 50, 2000);">Draw Line</button>
```

**And my js looks like :**

```
 function drawAnimatedLine(startPt, endPt, steps, time, fn) {
            var style = {
                strokeColor: "#0500bd",
                strokeWidth: 15,
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeColor: '#0000ff'
            };
            var directionX = (endPt.x - startPt.x) / steps;
            var directionY = (endPt.y - startPt.y) / steps;
            var i = 0;
            var prevLayer;
            var lineDraw = setInterval(function () {
                console.log("Inside Animate Line");
                if (i > steps) {
                    clearInterval(lineDraw);
                    if (fn)
                        fn();
                    return;
                }
                var newEndPt = new ol.geom.Point(startPt.x + i * directionX, startPt.y + i * directionY);
                var line = new ol.geom.LineString([startPt, newEndPt]);
                var fea = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry:line,
                    style: style
                });
                var vec = new ol.layer.Vector();
                vec.addFeatures([fea]);
                map.addLayer(vec);
                if(prevLayer)
                {
                    map.removeLayer(prevLayer);
                }
                prevLayer = vec;
                i++;
            }, time / steps);
        }
```

**Note : Coordinates will be dynamic but for testing I've passed the sample data in onclick of the button. Please do try to sort out this issue as soon as possible.**

Comment: What is your question? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: You have to try to sort out the issue as soon as possible

Comment: @JonatasWalker my issue is that I am not able to draw any line...no line is visible on the map.

Comment: There are several errors. My advice to you is: **start as simple as you can**, remove all that `setInterval` stuff, just add a `lineString` on the map with the button.

Comment: @JonatasWalker yes its making a line.But when I am using setInterval, nothing is happening.

Comment: So let's build a build a fiddle together. Create it with your code.

Comment: @JonatasWalker I have made a fiddle. It's my first fiddle so I m unable to load few resources. So , please have a look and correct it. Link is : 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishannigam9/byzs8bpL/)

Comment: @JonatasWalker I've successfully made the animation buddy.

Comment: Post the updated fiddle link.

Comment: @JonatasWalker I'll be posting the working example on SO by evening. Ok.